# TRANSACTIONS to CUSTOMERS Relationship

Tags: netsuite

We have the data tables from Netsuite ELT'd into a DW. I'm trying to build a query that relates `TRANSACTIONS` or `TRANSACTION_LINES` to the `CUSTOMERS` table.

What I've tried:

1.) transaction and `transaction_lines` does not have a `customer_id` so there's no direct join available

2.) None of the transaction mapping or link tables contain the customer id

3.) I've been browsing the schema browser `https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/odbc/record/transaction.html`, but I simply cannot figure out how to relate these two entities

Does anyone know how to relate transactions to customers?

Please note: This is specifically related to the Netsuite data model and how these two tables relate to each other. I'm not specifically looking for any SQL help, strictly how to associate a transaction with a customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joining field is `entity_id` on transactions

```sql
select tl.item_id, tl.item_count 
    from transaction_lines tl, transactions t, customers c
where  
    c.customer_id = t.entity_d and tl.transaction_id = t.transaction_id
```

Your syntax may vary